# SBT package produces empty JAR after enhancing compiled classes

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am an author of a SBT plugin: https://github.com/atais/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave

It's purpose is to **enhance** compiled classes using provided `StaticWeaveProcessor`.

To achieve this step I have overriden the `compile` step with:

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    ... 
    // https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Dynamic-Task.html#build.sbt+v2
    compile in Compile := Def.taskDyn {
      val c = (compile in Compile).value
      Def.task {
        (copyResources in Compile).value // we need to copy META-INF folder first, https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3934
        weaveTask.value
        c
      }
    }.value
  )
```

### Problem

Projects using this plugin compile properly, but they **might** produce an **empty jar**, during `package` or `publish` **IF** the compiled sources are not available beforehand.

You might want to check my pull-request where I have prepared a test project with test scenario.
https://github.com/atais/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/pull/2

### Details

I have tried printing all the settings and mappings, but they seem fine.

However, I have found, that `Package.Configuration` step is using `cacheStoreFactory: CacheStoreFactory` which I think is my problem.

during the function `makeJar(sources.toSeq, jar.file, manifest, log)` there is a `log.debug(sourcesDebugString(sources))` which gives empty result on first run:

```
[info] Finished EclipseLink static weaving in 610 ms.
[info] Packaging /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/test_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[debug] Input file mappings:
[debug]
```

but properly lists files on the second:

```
[info] Finished EclipseLink static weaving in 559 ms.
[info] Packaging /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/test_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[debug] Input file mappings:
[debug]         META-INF/persistence.xml
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/META-INF/persistence.xml
[debug]         META-INF
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/META-INF
[debug]         com
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/com
[debug]         META-INF/orm-rtb.xml
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/META-INF/orm-rtb.xml
[debug]         com/github/atais/entity
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/com/github/atais/entity
[debug]         com/github
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/com/github
[debug]         com/github/atais
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/com/github/atais
[debug]         com/github/atais/entity/EntityB.class
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/com/github/atais/entity/EntityB.class
[debug]         com/github/atais/entity/EntityA.class
[debug]           /home/atais/Documents/sbt-eclipselink-static-weave/sbt-test/target/scala-2.12/classes-weaved/com/github/atais/entity/EntityA.class
```

**SBT is not restarted** between this runs. It's just second time I call package.

How could I produce proper jar on first run?

Comment: I am afraid I miss the question. What do you expect to achieve? You want the jar not to be empty? Or you want SBT restarted?

Comment: Jar should not be empty

Comment: Any update/resolution on this?

Comment: @amateur-coder I think I fixed it after 2 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it turned out I should have used

```
productDirectories in Compile := Seq(weavedClassesDest.value),
```

instead of

```
products in Compile := Seq(weavedClassesDest.value),
```

and now it seems to be working